# In jVI for Netbeans, the cursor won't appear

Tags: vim, netbeans-7, key-bindings, jvi

Depending on the font I use, I might see a quarter of a cursor (lower right rectangle not flashing) in the wrong place, or no cursor at all. Still, the line I'm on highlights and the column number is displayed in the lower right.

I've tried a mix of fixed-width fonts at a mix of sizes (11-14), including the default Monospace, MacVim's Menlo, the awful Courier, and another q-a site's suggested Consolas.

Any ideas how to get the cursor to show up would be great. Alternate ways to get Vi keybindings in NetBeans also acceptable, though it seems jVi is the most current / active effort.

NetBeans 7.1.2

EDIT:
Image showing no cursor with highlighting
[image: No-cursor image]

Image showing actually two partial cursors, which I'd never seen before:
[image: Half-cursor image]

Comment: A screenshot or video might be helpful.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how not seeing the thing that isn't there is going to add information, but give me a sec :)....

Comment: Well you mentioned seeing "a quarter of a cursor" in "the wrong place".

Comment: Looks like jVi draws its own cursor. I would suggest you to send a bugreport to the author of jVi.

Comment: I don't have a sourcefourge login, sorry. Anyone who has an acct and cares to file a report can do so [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=3653&atid=103653)

Answer (score 13):

There is a problem with the Mac Retina, which is like this problem. The latest jVi release has a workaround, you need to turn on the option

Tools > Options > jViConfig > Platform > MacRetinaCursorXorBug

Comment: I don't have a Mac or retina display and still had this problem.

Comment: I'm using Linux and this option has been useful.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in Netbeans 8.0.2. Workaround for this is to disable following option:
Tools->Options->jVi config->platform->use modal frame

I found the solution [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jvi/discussion/10909/thread/80f191d3/) which solves other problems with cursor too. I hope this will help you.

Cheers

Comment: I would also suggest to set blinking frequency a little bit higher than 300 ms, let's say to 500 ms which improved cursor behavior in general.

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu - 14.04
java 1.7.0_121
netbeans - 8.2
jvi - 1.5.4

i had the same issue and 'use model frame' was already enabled. Enabling 'MacRetinaCursorXorBug' fixed the issue. i have set the frequency of the cursor to 500 to be on the safer side.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the option *MacRetinaCursorXorBug* under *Tools > Options > jViConfig > Platform* was the only working solution for me among a bunch of other suggested workarounds. So it's important to mention that this setting could be required even on non Mac Systems.

(Tested on environment: Netbeans IDE 8.0.2, Ubuntu 15.04 with Kernel 3.19.0-16, XFCE-Desktop 4.12, VirtualBox 4.3.28)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Tested on Netbeans 8.0.2, Arch Linux (4.0.7-2-ARCH) with KDE-plasma 5 desktop

Answer (score 0):

Setting the blink rate to 500 as suggested by develucas fixed this for me on Ubuntu and Netbeans 8.1, though it still disappears whilst moving it reappears shortly after it becomes stationary, makes jvi useable again.